# how is the final color of a rendered mesh is determined?

Tags: three.js

We give color while initializing a material. We also specify a color while initializing ambient and directional light sources. How is the final color of the mesh is determined.

I see no change in the final color of mesh when i change the color of the material. However the rendered color of the mesh is changing while i change the color of light sources (ambient or directional).

So

1) what is the use of specifying a color, while initializing a material ?, and

2) How is the final color of the mesh is determined

```js
darkMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
darkMaterialL = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
darkMaterialP = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );

var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x00ff00);
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0x000000);
light.position.set(0,150,100);

scene.add(ambientLight);
scene.add(light);
```

The above are the lights and materials i used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a jsfiddle for you to take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/fnR4E/

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry    = new Array();
var material    = new Array();
var mesh        = new Array();
var light;
var angle = 0.1;

init();
render();

function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    camera.position.y = 5;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    geometry[0] = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 8, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI);
    geometry[1] = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 8, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI);
    geometry[2] = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 8, 6, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0, Math.PI);

    material[0] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
    material[1] = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ ambient: 0xffffff, color: 0x00FF00 });
    material[2] = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ ambient: 0xffffff, color: 0xdddddd, specular: 0xFFFFFF, shininess: 15 });

    mesh[0] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry[0], material[0]);
    mesh[1] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry[1], material[1]);
    mesh[2] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry[2], material[2]);

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x007700);
    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
    light.position.set(0, 2, 0);

    scene.add(ambientLight);
    scene.add(light);

    mesh[0].position.set(-2, 0, 0);
    mesh[2].position.set(2, 0, 0);

    scene.add(mesh[0]);
    scene.add(mesh[1]);
    scene.add(mesh[2]);

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    camera.position.x = 5 * Math.cos(angle);
    camera.position.z = 5 * Math.sin(angle);

    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    angle += 0.01;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

The first mesh is using MeshBasicMaterial which essentially means it is lit by material color alone, for proof you can change the values of ambientLight and light to whatever you want and it won't effect the rendered color of this mesh.

The following two meshes (the first is MeshLambertMaterial and the second is MeshPhongMaterial) use both lights.  For additional reading on the theory behind each of the shading models (Lambertian and Phong) check out these excellent wikipedia articles:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambertian_reflectance
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phong_reflection_model

Here is a more "practical" explanation of what is going on (but you'll probably at least want to refer to the wiki articles for the equations that are discussed below):

The ambientLight is multiplied by the material 'ambient' value to produce the mesh ambient color.  This color only gets used up to the amount specified by the diffuse color of the material.  For example, if material ambient value is 0xFFFFFF and AmbientLight is 0x00FF00 then the mesh has a fully green ambient light - but, if the diffuse color of the material ('color') contains NO green color channel (e.g. 0xFF00FF) then there is no ambient light applied to the mesh. Alternatively, if there is a diffuse color of 0x007700 (half of the full green channel) then you will see ambient light on the object of the color 0x007700.

The diffuse color is denoted by the material 'color' value. This is the perceived color of the mesh.  In both the Lambert and BlinnPhong shading models this color is multiplied by the dot product of the vertex or fragment normal with the light vector.  In essence, this means that the more directly lit a vertex or fragment is - the closer to the full diffuse color it will be.  A vertex or fragment that is not directly lit by a light source at all is black.  AmbientLight sources are not included in this dot product calculation.

NOTE: Occluding meshes are *not* accounted for in this dot product calculation.  Only the angle between the light source and the vertex or fragment is considered.

Finally, the MeshPhongMaterial uses an additional property called specular.  This is the reflective light that produces the "shiny" spot on a mesh.  This comes from calculating the angle of reflection against the normal from the light source.  The material property 'specular' determines the color of this reflection spot.  Once again, AmbientLight sources are not included in this lighting calculation.

NOTE: Once again, occluding meshes are *not* accounted for in this calculation.

Fixed the problem.

Comment: Apparently I'm not allowed to post more than two links due to my reputation being under 10.  Both of the wiki articles are worth including, so, I wrote them as a single link - hopefully someone with more than 10 rep will fix that by putting them on different lines.  If not, it should be easy enough to figure out which is which.